# Oracle DB | Node.js - Insertion Event Tracking

Tags: node.js, oracle, events, node-oracledb

DB Team inserts new data into a table. If new data is inserted I do need to send messages.

Is there any way I could track new data using Nodejs. There is no specific duration for data insertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DB is remoteDB then you do require full-duplex connection.

After getting successful connections from the telnet from both servers do as follows:

```
const connection = await oracledb.getConnection({
    user          : user,
    password      : password,  
    connectString : connectString,
    events        : true
});

function myCallback(message) {
    console.log('CQN Triggered');
}

const options = {
     callback: myCallback,                     // method called by notifications        
     sql: `SELECT ID FROM table where STATUS= 0`,   // query
     timeout: 600,
     qos :  oracledb.SUBSCR_QOS_ROWIDS, // SUBSCR_QOS_QUERY: generate notifications when new rows with STATUS= 0 are found
     clientInitiated : true           //By Default it's false.
};

await connection.subscribe('mysub', options);
```

Answer (score 0):

See the node-oracledb documentation on [Continuous Query Notification](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#cqn), which lets your Node.js app be notified if data has changed in the database.

There are examples in [cqn1.js](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/main/examples/cqn1.js) and [cqn2.js](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/main/examples/cqn2.js).  When using Oracle Database and Oracle client libraries 19.4, or later, you'll find testing easier if you set the optional subscriptions attribute `clientInitiated` property to `true`:

```
const connection = await oracledb.getConnection({
    user          : "hr",
    password      : mypw,  // mypw contains the hr schema password
    connectString : "localhost/XEPDB1",
    events        : true
});

function myCallback(message) {
    console.log(message);
}

const options = {
    sql            : `SELECT * FROM mytable`,   // query of interest
    callback       : myCallback,                // method called by notifications
    clientInitated : true
};

await connection.subscribe('mysub', options);
```

You could also look at [Advanced Queuing](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#aq) as another way to propagate messages, though you would still need to use something like a table trigger or CQN to initiate an AQ message.

Comment: I have followd everything from the doc but still I am not getting any notification.

Note: My DB is on live server and my nodeJs application is running in my local machine.

Comment: Ask a new question here on StackOverflow or on GitHub and give _all_ the details.

Comment: I had followed your every process. But I am not getting the notifications. 
Note : I am inserting data from Dbeaver.

Comment: I'm happy to help, but you will need to provide much more information, including version numbers.  Either open a new question, or update your original quesiton.

Comment: I have followed the above steps but I am not getting the CQN notifications. Also I do have a confusion. While I do run the query 'SELECT * FROM USER_SYS_PRIVS WHERE PRIVILEGE= 'CHANGE NOTIFICATION' the ADMIN_OPTION column is NO. Is that would create a problem?